# ESP-IDF: not able to connect WIFI with long SSID name

Tags: esp32, freertos

ESP32 is not able to connect Long wifi SSID.

A wifi hotspot is created with longer SSID name and password.

example :

ssid="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234"

password="TestPassword@abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234"

Below code works well for small WiFi SSID [up to around 25 character long]. But unable to connect with longer WiFi SSID

```
ReturnCode WifiMgr::StartConnect(char* ssid, char* pw) {
esp_err_t err = ESP_OK;
wifi_config_t wifi_config{};

strlcpy(reinterpret_cast<char*>(wifi_config.sta.ssid), ssid);
strlcpy(reinterpret_cast<char*>(wifi_config.sta.password), pw);

if (err == ESP_OK) {
    err = esp_wifi_set_config(WIFI_IF_STA, &wifi_config);
    if (err != ESP_OK) {
        LogError(("esp_wifi_set_config() failed: %s", esp_err_to_name(err)));
    }
}

if (err == ESP_OK) {
    connecting_ = true;

    LogInfo(("StartConnect(): Attempting to connect to ssid: %s", wifi_config.sta.ssid));

    err = esp_wifi_connect();
    if (err != ESP_OK) {
        LogError(("esp_wifi_connect() failed: %s", esp_err_to_name(err)));

        connecting_ = false;
    }
}

return (err == ESP_OK) ? ReturnCode::kSuccess : ReturnCode::kFailure;
}
```

Wifi event handler code is as below

```
    void WifiMgr::WifiEventHandler(int32_t event_id, void* event_data) {

.....My tre code .....

    switch (event_id) {
        case WIFI_EVENT_SCAN_DONE:
            .....My tre code .....
            break;
        case WIFI_EVENT_STA_START:
            .....My tre code .....
            break;
        case WIFI_EVENT_STA_STOP:
            .....My tre code .....
            break;
        case WIFI_EVENT_STA_CONNECTED:
            ///// print connected
            break;
        case WIFI_EVENT_STA_DISCONNECTED:
            LogInfo(("WIFI_EVENT_STA_DISCONNECTED: ssid: %.*s reason: %d", info.disconnected->ssid_len, reinterpret_cast<char*>(info.disconnected->ssid), info.disconnected->reason));
            .....My tre code .....
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
.....My tre code .....

}
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include a complete but minimal program that does nothing but try to connect to WiFi and demonstrates the issue. This should be something that other people can build themselves, so *complete* but minimal, doing nothing else than demonstrate the problem. Otherwise  you're omitting potentially important parts of the program, and no one is going to write the missing parts just to test your problem.

Answer (score 1):

According to the docs, [the maximum length for the SSID value is 32](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/api-reference/network/esp_wifi.html#_CPPv416wifi_ap_config_t), and 64 for the password.

Comment: How does this answer the question? There's no indication that the person asking it used an SSID or password longer than the limits, and only mentions 25 character SSIDs as having a problem. The examples provided in the question are of legal length.